# create named vector from variables

Tags: r

I want to use named vectors in a function of mine and I need the vector names from variables.

Example:

I want to create the vector

```
c(foo = 1, bar = -1)
```

in the following way:

```
a = "foo"
b = "bar"

c(a = 1, b = -1)

# where  c(a = 1, b = -1) == c(foo = 1, bar = -1)
```

Is there a way of using variables as names for vectors? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We can use `setNames`

```
setNames(c(1, -1), c(a, b))
#  foo bar 
#  1  -1
```

---

Or another option is `lst` from `dplyr` to create a `list` and then `unlist`

```
library(dplyr)
unlist(lst(!! a := 1, !! b := -1))
#   foo bar 
#   1  -1
```

Comment: Wow that is easy. Thanks for the answer! I will accept it as soon as I can.